# Context in transactions with Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I need to use mongoid's transactions to execute some operations while keeping consistency in case of failure.

Following the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-transactions/), I understand that I have to initiate a session on a model and execute the operations between `start_transaction` y `commit_transaction`.

The thing I do not understand is the fact that I have to instantiate a session on a specific model or instance of a model.

I do not get if it is because the model posses a helper to execute that operation (due to beign `Monogid::Document`) or maybe the operations I have to execute must be related to the model/instance used.

I mean, should I be able to execute this (I understand that is more or less wrong cause these model might be totally unrelated):

```rb
ModelA.with_session do |s|
  s.start_transaction
  TotallyUnrelatedModelA.create!
  TotallyUnrelatedModelB.create!
  TotallyUnrelatedModelC.create!
  s.commit_transaction
end
```

Anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid doesn't implement (or have) transactions at this time. That is a driver feature.

You shouldn't be calling `commit_transaction` as that is the first iteration of the transaction API exposed by the driver and doesn't support automatic retries. Mongoid documentation unfortunately hasn't yet been updated to show the correct API to use - it is the `with_transaction` method as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-transactions/).

To use a transaction on the driver level, the session that the transaction is started on must be passed to every operation manually, as shown [in the same doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-transactions/).

Mongoid doesn't have that requirement via what it calls a *persistence context*. This feature is somewhat described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#custom), the gist of it is you can override where a model is read from or written to at runtime to e.g. write to another collection.

Sessions are implemented via this same runtime override. Review [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-sessions/). The `with_session` method retrieves the *client* from the active persistence context, then ensures that 1) there is a session active on that client and 2) the active persistence context is associated with that session, so that 3) each persistence operation (read & write) would specify that session to the driver.

Now, to answer your question:

> The thing I do not understand is the fact that I have to instantiate a session on a specific model or instance of a model.

Mongoid needs to know what client to start the session on. It can get that client from any persistence context. It doesn't matter if you use a model class or a model instance. Because only one session can be active at a time within Mongoid (the session is stored in thread-local storage for the current thread), you must use only models that are associated with the same client that you used for starting the session, via the `with_session` method, regardless of how that client is arrived at by Mongoid (be that via a model class or a model instance).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am afraid I don't totally understand. [Here (Mongoid documentation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-transactions/) explains how to start sessions, execute transactions and retry them with Mongoid.